# WINS на Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, wins, сервер

Здравствуйте! Админю небольшую сеть - 5 компов +сервер, на котором решил включить WINS. Добавил роль, прописал на всех компах ip адрес wins-сервака... В результате, при попытке просмотреть компьютеры рабочей группы с любого компа, получаю следующее:

> Нет доступа к Rsk. Возможно, у вас нет прав на использование этого сетевого ресурса. Обратитесь к администратору этого сервера для получения соответствующих прав.
> Не найден сетевой путь.

До этого, при добавлении нового компа в сеть, пересоздал базу данных wins. Пробовал создавать статическое сопоставление... Эффект нулевой...

Comment: А RSK это имя вашего сервера?)

Comment: Да, надо было уточнить, RSK - это имя рабочей группы, имя сервера - server

Answer (score 1):

На кой Вам это старье?Сделайте сервант принудительно Master Browser